# NGINX, upstream and location, how to redirect as absolute URL?

Tags: nginx

Basically I have a problem when I try to redirect http://localhost/report I would like that it redirects to my app that has a route / but instead I get `Cannot GET /report/`

What do I have to add to my nginx.conf?

Here is it:

```
http {
  upstream nodeapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:9876;
    keepalive 64;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    location /report {
      proxy_pass http://nodeapp;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I think you just need to add a trailing slash to the `proxy_pass` directive: `proxy_pass http://nodeapp/;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
location /report/ {
  # this slash  ^ and this V
  proxy_pass http://nodeapp/;
}
```

Read documentation on [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass) and [`location`](http://nginx.org/r/location).